# Brake shoes rubbing on drum

Tags: brakes, drum-brakes

I recently installed new brake shoes on my car's rear drum brakes. Although the brakes are working ok I noticed the shoes are rubbing slightly on one wheel. It's only rubbing on one spot and I can still spin the wheel quite easily. Would that indicate that there's a problem with the drum? There's nothing obviously wrong with the drum and the brakes are installed correctly.

Comment: Some drums get bent due to people smacking them with a hammer to get them off - especially those who have little experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn’t sound like anything to be worried about, slight variations as you rotate the wheel are fairly typical.